# Swift posting to Facebook not working?

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, uiimage

I'm trying to post a photo to Facebook, and it works fine using the following code:

```
   func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

        self.selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        var photo = FBSDKSharePhoto()
        photo.image = self.selectedImage
        photo.userGenerated = true

        var content = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
        content.photos = [photo]


        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        shareDialog.fromViewController = self
        shareDialog.shareContent = content
        shareDialog.show()

}
```

However, this only works when the user has the facebook app downloaded. otherwise it does NOT open the web browser to share the photo, even though facebook state:

> The Share Dialog switches to the native Facebook for iOS app, then
>   returns control to your app after a post is published. **If someone
>   doesn't have Facebook app installed it will automatically falls back
>   to a web-based dialog.**

Any suggestions please ? answers appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Use "SLComposeViewController" It will work fine....

Comment: @Joge but that just posts directly from my app? its supposed to open the browser and share it.

Comment: SLComposeViewController work in direct app ..... no need to import facebook sdk .. Only need to add Social Kit

Comment: @Joge right, but it gives that ugly looking view controller in the app, or can it be customised?

Comment: Its default controller of apple ...

Comment: Could you share whole code? shareDialog initialisation is missing.
Also try 
shareDialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeAutomatic

[FBSDKShareDialogMode](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/constants/FBSDKShareDialogMode/)

Comment: @BhupendraSingh of course sorry, the sharedialog is initialised at the very top of the screen. I tried the mode automatic and it still doesn't work.

Comment: 1. share validateWithError: check what is error there.
[FBSDKSharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBSDKSharing/) 

If 1 is not useful enough then 

2. Try implementing Share Dialog delegate <FBSDKSharingDelegate>, and listen to error. In that case you need to set delete before show.

Comment: @BhupendraSingh right ok, thank you for the help. i will try

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
func postToFacebook(image: UIImage!) {
    var SocialMedia :SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    SocialMedia.completionHandler = {
        result -> Void in
        var getResult = result as SLComposeViewControllerResult;
        switch(getResult.rawValue) {
        case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Cancelled.rawValue: println("Cancelled")
        case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Done.rawValue: println("It's Work!")
        default: println("Error!")
        }
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    self.presentViewController(SocialMedia, animated: true, completion: nil)
    SocialMedia.setInitialText("...")
    SocialMedia.addImage(image)
}
```